# App crash when receives push notification and CGM intent service not being called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

There must be something I'm doing wrong but I'm new in android studio and I can't find it. I have an app which displays four webViews, each in a tab and I'm trying to send a push, the json response code is ok, but I've established some breakpoints in my GCM class and it looks like it's never called and my app crash when push "arrives" but without display any push notification.

json response code:

```
{"multicast_id":4710708383941694704,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1431447972667924%e17d0a39f9fd7ecd"}]}{"registration_ids":["XxxxXXx"],"data":{"message":"New content available!"}}
```

this is my activity main file when I have my GCM intent service:

```
   public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }


    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                    // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
            // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

        // Put the message into a notification and post it.
        // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
        // a GCM message.
        private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_guias)
                            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(msg))
                            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".MainActivity$GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".inicioActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inicio" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActividadesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actividades" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
05-13 10:50:19.329  17900-17900/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-13 10:50:19.329  17900-17900/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-13 10:50:31.209  17900-17900/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1768)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 10:50:31.419      185-201/? E/﹕ Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
05-13 10:50:35.179      274-274/? E/Launcher﹕ setWindowOpaque()
05-13 10:50:35.269      274-274/? E/Launcher﹕ MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished.
05-13 10:50:38.559      274-274/? E/Launcher﹕ setWindowOpaque()
05-13 10:52:38.579      185-215/? E/PowerManagerService﹕ CurLock p:3 mPS:1
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean by trace? there is no error, it works fine and as you can see the json says the gcm message was sent ok. But my device never receive that message, an therefore my GCM Intent Service never called...

Comment: i mean add some Log messages to your gcm service / gcm registration process and then post these logs

Comment: Added logcat, hope it will be helpfull

Comment: so just to make sure that registration is going well replace mDisplay with some reference of a Visible TextView so you can check the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your `GcmBroadcastReceiver`. The permission and the category are wrong. The receiver entry in the manifest should look something like this:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiaswebtabapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also add a log to the receiver to check if it's being called. A GCM message triggers the receiver, then the receiver triggers the service.

Comment: how can I add a log to the receiver?

Comment: I've fixed my manifest file and edited here with new manifest file but GCM intent service is still not getting called.

Comment: @user3033437 `Log.d("Receiver", "onReceiver");` in the `onReceiver` method of your broadcast receiver.... is your receiver getting called?

Comment: @user3033437 your previous permission was correct. sorry about that... only your category needed correction

Comment: I've established breakpoints in onReceive method, but it's not being called, that's the main problem and why I have posted here

Comment: @user3033437 can you try moving the Broadcast Receiver out of `MainActivity`?

Comment: Thank you very much @LordRaydenMK it worked just like you said, moving it out of mainActivity. I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I fixed it by adding a filter to my `extras` inside `public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService` like this:

```
if(extras.getString("from").toString().equals(YOUR_SENDERID)){
                    sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString(),extras);
                    Log.i("not an error received "+TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("error received "+TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
```